# Using KSOAP for file transfer from android application to web service

Tags: android, ksoap

I have sent the data from the android application to the webservice which further will transfer it to the browser by using KSOAP. now i am planning to transfer a file from the app  to the web service. Is it possible?

Comment: you may convert the file as bytes and transfer it

Comment: can't it be send directly??

Comment: what kind of files you suppose to send?

Comment: it can be any file.. text file, image file etc.

Comment: Yes you can do it by file streaming method...

Answer (score 2):

```
InputStream is = null;
try{
    is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/Filename"));
}   
catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}   

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {
    while (is.available() > 0) {
        bos.write(is.read());
    }
} 
catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();               
String base64= Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

1st step: Get the file from the SDcard and assign that file in **INPUTSTREAM**.

2nd step: Write the file into **BYTEARRAYOUTPUTSTREAM**

3rd step: Convert that Stream into **BYTEARRAY**

4th step: Convert Bytearray into **BASE64STRING**

Comment: @PriyanRockZ http://android-spirit.blogspot.in/2013/08/uploading-file-to-webservice-using-ksoap.html for reference visit that